# How to loop multidimensional JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json object and I want loop it. Here is my JSON object

```
  [
    [
        {
            "adress": "8714 Pritchard Place 70118",
            "lat": "29.97646",
            "lng": "-90.13351"
        },
        {
            "adress": "p o box 13888 70185",
            "lat": "29.9639859",
            "lng": "-90.1220795"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3848 Cambaronne St 70118",
            "lat": "29.963181",
            "lng": "-90.11288230000002"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3023 Baudin St 70119",
            "lat": "29.9676822",
            "lng": "-90.098581"
        },
        {
            "adress": "400 N Galvez St 70119",
            "lat": "29.963966",
            "lng": "-90.087711"
        },
        {
            "adress": "2240 Louis St 70117",
            "lat": "29.9645507",
            "lng": "-90.0799022"
        },
        {
            "adress": "1554 Conti St # 9 70112",
            "lat": "29.9609508",
            "lng": "-90.074644"
        },
        {
            "adress": "1830 St. Phillip St. 70116",
            "lat": "29.967337",
            "lng": "-90.07302500000003"
        },
        {
            "adress": "1917 N Johnson St 70116",
            "lat": "29.972193",
            "lng": "-90.0674779"
        },
        {
            "adress": "1861 N. Galvez Street 70113",
            "lat": "29.9774886",
            "lng": "-90.063018"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "adress": "2603 St Anthony St 70119",
            "lat": "29.9836",
            "lng": "-90.063042"
        },
        {
            "adress": "2327 Aubry St 70119",
            "lat": "29.9830524",
            "lng": "-90.0698395"
        },
        {
            "adress": "832 N White St 70119",
            "lat": "29.9798109",
            "lng": "-90.07934879999999"
        },
        {
            "adress": "2753 Orleans Ave 70117",
            "lat": "29.972751",
            "lng": "-90.083087"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3801 Burxelles St., Apt A 70122",
            "lat": "29.992967",
            "lng": "-90.071667"
        },
        {
            "adress": "4332 Perlita St 70126",
            "lat": "29.998463",
            "lng": "-90.0761284"
        },
        {
            "adress": "5026 St Anthony Ave., Apt C 70122",
            "lat": "30.0046184",
            "lng": "-90.0759097"
        },
        {
            "adress": "5026 St. Anthony Ave Apt C 70122",
            "lat": "30.0092872",
            "lng": "-90.0649152"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3636 Frenchmen St 70122",
            "lat": "30.003136",
            "lng": "-90.0612"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3635 Frenchmen St. 70122",
            "lat": "29.995591",
            "lng": "-90.060578"
        },
        {
            "adress": "2666 Acacia St 70122",
            "lat": "29.9967787",
            "lng": "-90.0515892"
        },
        {
            "adress": "2701 Treasure St 70122",
            "lat": "29.993659",
            "lng": "-90.046275"
        },
        {
            "adress": "3245 Montegut St 70126",
            "lat": "29.995422",
            "lng": "-90.040324"
        },
        {
            "adress": "4221 Old Gentilly Rd 70126",
            "lat": "30.000224",
            "lng": "-90.044552"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<javascript_array.length;i++)
{
 alert(( javascript_array[i] ));
}But it returns object

Comment: Um, you have an array of arrays... Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jsonObject = [
            [
                {
                    "adress": "8714 Pritchard Place 70118",
                    "lat": "29.97646",
                    "lng": "-90.13351"
                },
                {
                    "adress": "p o box 13888 70185",
                    "lat": "29.9639859",
                    "lng": "-90.1220795"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "adress": "2603 St Anthony St 70119",
                    "lat": "29.9836",
                    "lng": "-90.063042"
                },
                {
                    "adress": "2327 Aubry St 70119",
                    "lat": "29.9830524",
                    "lng": "-90.0698395"
                }
            ]
        ]
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var i in jsonObject) {
            for(var j in jsonObject[i]) {
                for(var k in jsonObject[i][j]) {
                    document.writeln("key = "+k+", value = "+jsonObject[i][j][k]+"<br>");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you have there is a Javascript object, JSON is a way of storing a javascript object in a readable form.

The reason that it is returning an object, is that you're referencing an object with your for loop. The for loop that you have given:

```
for(i=0;i<javascript_array.length;i++) {
  alert(( javascript_array[i] ));
}
```

In this case javascript_array.length would return 2, as there are two arrays within your first array. You will need to iterate over the array returned with another for loop, at which you will be presented with another object containing the values that you require (addr, longitude and latitude). These will need to be iterated over in order to retrieve them as well.